# Swift Timer SK.wait

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, skphysicsbody

I have balls spawning every 3 seconds and I want the balls to spawn faster if the score increases. The problem is my spawnrate stays the same 4 seconds and does not change when my score increases. Thanks for the helps m8s

```
  var spawnRate : TimeInterval = 4

    var  wait = SKAction .wait(forDuration: spawnRate, withRange: 0.2)

    if score >= 6  {
        spawnRate = 3
        wait = SKAction .wait(forDuration: spawnRate, withRange: 0.2)
    }
     let spawning = SKAction.sequence([wait,spawn])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather refactor the code, and double check that score is really increased , plus cancel previous actions, in case they have not finished after previous launch. My assumption that you produce several actions and they are "accumulated" in the future.

```
        var spawnRate : TimeInterval
        var wait:SKAction!

        if score >= 6  {
            spawnRate = 3
            wait = SKAction .wait(forDuration: spawnRate, withRange: 0.2)
        }
        else {
            spawnRate = 4
            wait = SKAction .wait(forDuration: spawnRate, withRange: 0.2)
        }

        let spawningKey ="spawningKey"
        self.spinnyNode?.removeAction(forKey: waitKey)

        let spawning = SKAction.sequence([wait,spawn])

        self.spinnyNode?.run(spawning, withKey: spawningKey)
```

Comment: any way i could contact you? I have a few questions please m8

Comment: OK) Just drop me a line on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/siarhei-yakushevich-3a7a9030